# How to create a route without action?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Is it possible to create a route without action?

I have this default route:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Default",
    url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

But I also I want to have URLs like this: `http://mysite/bar/1234` where `1234` is the `ID` and `bar` is the controller.

So I created the following route:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "BarRoute",
    url: "{controller}/{id}",
    defaults: new { controller = "bar", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

But when I navigate to `http://mysite/bar/1234`, it said the resource is not found. What did I do wrong in the second route?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot have the following 2 routes in that order without any constraints

- `{controller}/{action}/{id}`
- `{controller}/{id}`

Those 2 routes are incompatible. When you attempt to access `http://mysite/bar/1234`, the routing engine is analyzing your routes and `/bar/1234` matches your first route. Except that I guess you do not have an action called `1234` on the `Bar` controller.

So if you want this setup to work you need to specify some [`constraints`](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/controllers-and-routing/creating-a-route-constraint-cs). Also don't forget that the order of your routes definition is important because they are resolved in the order you defined them. So make sure you place more specific routes at the top.

Answer (score 5):

```
routes.MapRoute(
  name:        "BarRoute",
  url:         "{controller}/{id}",
  defaults:    new { controller = "Bar", action = "Index" },
  constraints: new { id = @"\d+" }
);
```

You have to take into account that your route has to be placed in appropriate place - before the more general routes, for example:

```
routes.MapRoute(
           name: "BarRoute",
routes.MapRoute(
           name: "Default",
```

Comment: Small mistake. A lot of research.